# CKEditor: Change background color of Link modal?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to change the background color of the CKEditor's link modal, but I can't figure how to edit the JS and make that happen. The background color is apparently defined in this JS bit:

```
<div tabIndex="-1" style="position: ',CKEDITOR.env.ie6Compat? "absolute":"fixed","; z-index: ",g,"; top: 0px; left: 0px;",!CKEDITOR.env.ie6Compat?"background-color: "+e:"",'" class="cke_dialog_background_cover">'],CKEDITOR.env.ie6Compat&&(e="<html><body style=\\'background-color:"+e+";\\'></body></html>"
```

The output is defined as "white", not #ffffff. The div in question is class "cke_dialog_background_cover".

Comment: Where is that code from? Why edit the JS and not override with CSS !important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS overrides, it's much easier than editing the core code.

Create a rule like this:

```
.cke_dialog_background_cover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

And it should work:

[image: CKEditor with modified modal background]